# Removing or hiding component on specific route path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my app when you click on the /favouritetabs route path, the Search bar is still rendered and ideally I'd like that to be not visible when on the favourites page.  Here's my code:

```
<div>
    <div>
       <SearchTab search={this.handleSubmit} value={this.handleChange}/>
    </div>
</div>

<Switch className="wrapper2 songContainer">
    <Route exact path="/home" render={props => <SongInfo {...props} artist={this.state.artistName} title={this.state.songTitle} link={this.state.tabId} />} />
    <Route exact path="/favouritetabs" component={FavouriteTabs} />} />
</Switch>
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Given the information, you seem to want to display the `SearchTab` always *except* for the route of `/favouritetabs`.

The simplest way of doing that here would be another `Switch` that checks for `/favouritetabs` in the first Route and the second would match on anything (or whatever you would like it to match on)

```
const searchTab = () => (
    <SearchTab 
        search={this.handleSubmit} 
        value={this.handleChange} />
);

// ...

<div>
    <div>
       <Switch>
           <Route exact path={`/favouritetabs`} component={null} />
           <Route component={searchTab} />
       </Switch>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me unless I'm doing it wrong. I replaced my top SearchTab surrounded by divs with the Switch that you wrote.

Comment: No there are are no errors but it stops the login feature from working and being able to navigate the site. The main page still shows up. Should the second Switch statement for route path favouritetabs stay the same?

Comment: I tested it locally before posting but one difference is I only had one switch in the component I used instead of two - what happens when you remove the other switch or swap their positions?

Comment: If I remove the other Switch that has paths home and favourite tabs in it, I just get the home screen and nothing works as expected. 

If I move the Switch that has only searchTab/what you wrote under the other Switch statement it still doesn't work.